# Legendre transformation of a piecewise function

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be defined by
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
1 & \text{ if } x<1 \\ 
3x-1 & \text{ if } x\geq 1 
\end{cases}$$
How do I determine the Legendre transform $f^*$ of $f$, and the Legendre transform $(f^{*})^*$ of $f^*$?

Given a function $g:A\to \mathbb{R}$, where $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}^k$, the definition of $g^*$ is defined by
$$g^*(p)=\sup\{xp-g(x)\mid x\in A\}$$
for $p\in \mathbb{R}^k$, where the supremum on the right side is finite.

Clearly, we have 
$$
\sup\{xp-f(x)\mid x <1\}=-1;\\
\sup\{xp-f(x)\mid x \geq 1\}=1.
$$
Determining the maximum of them, we get that $f^*(p)=1$ and the domain of $f^*$ is $\{3\}$. Am I understanding this correctly? The Legendre transform has different names, such as a Legendre-Fenchel or a conjugate function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

$$f^*(p) = \max \Big\{ \sup_{x<1} \big(y x -1\big), \sup_{x\geq 1} \big( y x - 3x+1\big)\Big\}$$

Now let's evaluate the first supremum in the max.

If $y<0$, then that supremum is $+\infty$ (by letting $x\to-\infty$).
If $y \geq 0$, then that supremum is $\lim_{x\to 1^-} (yx-1)=y-1$.

Now argue similarly for the second supremum and put it all together.

Comment: Wow, that's easier than I thought. I've not thought the way you have just shown. Thank you for that. I have another similar question about finding the supremum of $\{xy-\frac{x^2}{2}\mid x\in [-1,1]\}$. Do you have time to help me with this one? Or can you confirm this: What I found out is that the supremum is $y^2/2$ if $y\in[-1,1]$, and $y-1/2$ if $y>1$ and $-y-1/2$ if $y<-1$.

Comment: Please post this as a separate question, the comments are not the right medium for that. The procedure is similar.

Comment: I have evaluated the second supremum, which I got as follows: If $y>3$ then the supremum is infinite, while if $y\leq 3$ then the supremum is $y-2$. So, when we are finding $f^*$, its domain must be $[0,3]$, and so the result is $\max\{y-1,y-2\}=y-1$ for all $y\in [0,3]$. Do you agree?